# Can I include the path and query string in an IIS "Error Pages" redirect?

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect, custom-errors

I'm setting up a custom 403.4 handler so that non-SSL requests to my site are redirected to a different URL - and what I'd like to do is to include the script path and query string in the redirect, so that a user who requests `http://www.site.com/foo?bar=1` will be redirected to `https://www.site.com/foo?bar=1`

I know something similar is possible when configuring a top-level site redirect, using the $S, $Q, %v tokens referred to in [this IIS reference page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true) - but this syntax doesn't seem to work when configuring a custom error redirect.

Comment: Easiest fix would be to set up a second site, assign the non-https binding and have that site redirect all requests to the https site